# Inductor in a DC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

I found this question,
I don't understand how could the current through 2R ,immediately after opening the circuit, be less than when the circuit is closed!
Shouldn't be an emf from the inductor that will increase the current in the circuit?
If not, what explains this problem?

The problem:
(All element of the circuits are ideal)There is no current in the circuit when the key is kept open,The key is closed for some period of time. It's known that before opening the key the current in 2R-resistor was 3 times higher than immediately after opening the key:

1) Find the current in 2R-resistor immediately after closing the key.

2) Find the current in the coil immediately after opening the key.

3) How much heat will be released from the circuit after opening the key?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some guidance.

1. You can't change the current in an ideal inductor instantaneously (in zero time). Therefore, whatever the current is in the inductor just prior to closing the key in part (a) it will be the same the instant after the key is closed. It will then change over time.
2. Likewise, whatever the current in the inductor is just prior to opening the key in part (b), the same current will flow in the inductor the instant after the key is opened. It will then change over time.
3. Finally, the only heating that occurs in a circuit occurs due to current flowing through resistance. Ideal inductors have no resistanc

Hope this helps.

Comment: For 3. You might add that the energy dissipated in the resistor as heat comes from the energy stored in the inductor?

Comment: That would be my solution, is it correct?
1) I1 = E/3R     

2) I2 = E/9R

3) Q = I2^2 . (2R/3)

Comment: @Farcher Yes, but I am never quite sure at what point to stop in helping with H&E questions.

Comment: Thanks, It's not my homework, I just included the topic as it fits. It was in an entrance exam to one of my friends :)

Comment: @Alpha Show your work for the answer to (3)

Comment: @BobD the emf released from the inductor will act as a battery connected with the resistances in parallel, thus Q = (the current flowing from the coil)^2 multiplied by the equivalent resistance of the circuit(2R/3) and delta t = 0

Comment: @Alpha But (3) talks about when the switch (key) is open.  When it is open R is no longer connected in parallel with 2R. All you have is 2R in parallel with L.  So  now how would you determine the TOTAL amount of heat that is dissipated in 2R? And where is that energy coming from?

Comment: @BobD Yes!! I made a mistake! but as I understand, it's only regarding the resistance, it would be 2R instead , and the same steps if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @Alpha The total amount of heat dissipated in 2R will have to equal the energy stored in the magnetic field of the inductor due to the current in the inductor, since  that is the only energy source available with the key open. Do you know the equation for the energy stored in the magnetic field of the inductor?

Comment: @BobD E = -L . dl/dt ?
but isn't it just a different representation of the formula I used?

Comment: @Alpha In your solution to (3) you are squaring the current in 2R that exists only at the instant the switch opens. After that the current decays exponentially eventually becoming zero. To get the total heat dissipated you would need to integrate the power dissipation over time. But what I've been trying to tell you is you don't need to do all that if you know the equation for the energy stored in the magnetic field of the inductor when the switch opens. And that energy is $$E=\frac{LI^2}{2}$$ where $I$ is the current you calculated in (2). All of that energy is dissipated in 2R as heat.

Answer (score 0):

I will only answer the first part of the question since the rest is very much homework-like.

When you open the switch, there is an EMF from the inductor because of the changing current, but you simultaneously lose the EMF from the voltage source E. Therefore the total EMF after opening the switch is not greater than before, hence the current does not increase.